# wierd desktop screen in Ubuntu 16

Tags: screen

Something goes wrong with my desktop screen as it shows **fault** screen instead of the wallpaper.[image: desktop]

But as i switch to other wallpaper it gets removed, and comes after each time i **log** on the pc.
I want to know the exact reason of the error.

Comment: What is your graphics card? What video driver are you using?

Comment: Nvidia geforce 940M

Comment: Graphics driver issue. Try reinstalling/updating the graphics driver.

Answer (score 0):

Answering instead of commenting as this might be long.

Try using these two commands to check for errors -

**dmesg** - Shows Boot Up Message and other Kernel related messages like device connections (When you plug in a new device eg: external hard drives, webcams, bluetooth devices...). Type dmesg in console and it will show you how the system booted up. If you have hard drive problems or any other booting problem they might show here.

**lspci** - Shows you all PCI devices (Video Card, Sound Card, Capture Card...)

Try using log files to see what the error might be.

Since behavior gets reperated, use `tail -f logfile`

Many errors are logged to `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and `~/.xsession-errors` while running X; errors in X itself to the first, and errors in programs running inside of X to the second.

Watching the log file in an open terminal with the tail command allows the user to see the last ten lines logged, followed by any errors as they are added to the log in realtime, allowing a user to more easily associate error messages with the issue needing troubleshooting. A user can simply 'tail' a log file, and then try to reproduce the error, watching for new lines to appear.

Other logs can be helpful to watch, such as `/var/log/dmesg` for messages from the kernel, for example, relating to USB devices as they are plugged in, hard disk failures, and other hardware issues.

Searching for the error message on the net might get you the solution.